# UE5 Crash minutes after opening a blank project - Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000000010

Tags: crash, unreal-engine5

I have no idea why, but any new Unreal project I try to open will crash within a few minutes of booting up. I've tried reinstalling, reverifying, upgrading my computer, getting more memory, etc. and nothing seems to work. Please help me.

[This is the crash report I get every single time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzk8A.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the "Default RHI" option in Project Settings to DirectX 11:

[image]